# GLOG - no output file log is created

Tags: c++, glog

i am tryng to implement the GLOG lib in my project, but i am only getting console outputs, and i cannot allow to create the file log with the severity asociated, here is my code: i am developing for linux (ubuntu)

```
#include <glog/logging.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    google::SetLogDestination(0,"/home/ricardo/Desktop/CODIGO/info.log");
    google::SetLogDestination(google::WARNING,"");
    FLAGS_logtostderr = 1;
    google::InitGoogleLogging("log_test");
    LOG(INFO) << "Found " << 2332 << " cookies";

     return 0;

}
```

any help?? 
thx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `google::SetLogDestination(google::WARNING,"");` looks pretty suspicious.

This line:

```
FLAGS_logtostderr = 1;
```

tells Glog to write to the console, instead of a file.  For details, see the section entitled *Setting Flags* in Google Log's how-to document: http://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html

If you want to write to a file, delete the line containing `FLAGS_logtostderr`.

Also, why not use `INFO` instead of `0` in the first case?  It would make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `FLAGS_logtostderr = 1;` you want `FLAGS_alsologtostderr=1;`

This will log to both a log file and to stderr.